# Prove that $tx+(1-t)x \ge x^ty^{1-t}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis

Given conditions are $x>0$ $y>0$ and $0 \le t \le 1$ There is a hint given which says $Log$ is a concave increasing function. How do I apply this here?

There is also a generalization of this problem with $m$ points instead of just 2 which says $$t^1x_1 + t^2x_2 \ldots + t^mx_m \ge x_1^{t^1} + x_2^{t^2} \ldots x_m^{t^m}$$ where $$ t^1 + t^2 \ldots + t^m = 1 $$

The second part of the generalization is simply proving that the arithmetic mean of $m$ numbers in $n$-dimension is greater than or equal to the geometric mean

$$ \dfrac {x_1 + x_2 \ldots + x_m}{m} \ge (x_1x_2\ldots x_m)^{\frac{1}{m}}$$

Comment: Are you sure the above inequality is right?

Comment: No. I fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a general concave function $f$, and  $t\in(0,1)$, we have
$$
f(tx + (1-t)y) \geq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)
$$

For your question, take logarithms of both sides to get 
$$
\log(tx + (1-t)y) \mbox{ vs } t\log(x) + (1-t)\log(y)
$$
And since $\log$ is concave, we would find the direction of the above versus to be $\geq$.

Since $\log$ is a strictly monotonic transformation, the inequality is preserved when we invert back to the original, i.e.
$$
tx + (1-t)y \geq x^ty^{1-t}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. For generalizing, I just use a similar notion for $m$ variables instead of $2$, right?

Comment: For generalization, you would need to do induction. If it is true for $n$ values, then it is true for $n+1$ values sort of an argument.